# Camera Module Turn LED Off

Tags: camera

I've made the disable_camera_led=1 change to the sudo nano /boot/config.txt and rebooted my Pi. The issue is the LED has stayed on?

How do I turn it off?

Comment: I think that the ability to turn off the LED in software depends on the camera that you are using.  What camera are you using?

Comment: It seems to be a bug it the current software http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=44759&p=355475 http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=44308&p=352456

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found that in one of the updates they actually [broke](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=44879) that feature. A subsequent update fixed it. So I would try updating again.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to turn off the camera led: [Here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/05/how-to-disable-the-red-led-on-the-pi-camera-module/)

You can also as the tutorial states, make a python script that turns the led on/off on different actions. Or just make a script that turns it off at startup.