# Red camera LED fails to turn off

Tags: pi-3, boot, camera, led, config.txt

I am using Raspbian 4.9.35-v7+ (3B+) and the camera: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1567.
This may be flagged as a duplicate to previous questions under similar titles; however, none of their answers were able to help.

[Camera Module Turn LED Off](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7527/camera-module-turn-led-off)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44759&p=355475

Unfortunately none of these helped. I have tried update, upgrade, reboot; disable_camera_led in boot config (saves after rebooting but does not take effect); camera.led = False; GPIO executable; and sudo rpi-update firmware looks to give an error of

```
*** Invalid hash given
```

So thus far during the preview and capture functions of the PiCamera, the red LED light is still on, and I would like to disable this LED at all times.

Comment: are you sure that you have the same camera as the link you posted? ... i do not see any LEDs at the link .... maybe yours is hardwired to the power .... cut the LED off

Comment: Good eye, picked the wrong one and I've updated now. LED is labeled D1. May not be so easy to cut it out.

Comment: black nail polish then (or black paint)